# WebView ignores img tag

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an HTML text with images from varying origins and WebView just ignores them. I only found how I can display images which are stored locally. How can I make the WebView display them?

Comment: `varying sources` ???

Comment: @greenapps not all images habe the same origin

Comment: I understand. But i do not understand that you do not clear up.